# Unit tests for lookup tables

Tags: unit-testing

I have a method that just receives a value and produces the result from a lookup table. The table is hand-written and contains about 100 records.
Everything is pretty simple, but the question is what’s the proper way to unit-test this code?
Should I create a separate test for every possible option, or just test several random inputs? Maybe there is a standard way for such cases that I’m unaware of?
Thank you!